# update postgresql with syntax errors

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have one table called test, which has 4 columns:

```
id     INT
v_out  INT
v_in   INT
label  CHARACTER
```

I'm trying to update the table with the following query:

```
String sql = "
update
    test
set
    v_out = temp.outV
    , v_in = temp.inV
    , label = temp.label
from (
        values
            (1,234,235,'[abc]') // these value are read from other places
            ,(2,234,5585,'[def]') //[abc] = object.toString();
    ) as temp (e_id, outV, inV, label)
where
    id = temp.e_id;
```

When I execute it, I got the error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "["

before get this error, i already update over 3000 rows.

so whats the reason caused this? is it because "[" this character?
this is the original table:

```
create table edges(
 id serial not null primary key,
 vertex_out int, 
 vertex_in int, 
 label character varying(255),
 constraint fk_vertex_out foreign key (vertex_out) references vertices(id) on delete cascade,
 constraint fk_vertex_in foreign key (vertex_in) references vertices(id) on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: This looks good: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d7f14/2 there must be something you are not telling us.

Comment: I doubt that `label` is of type `CHARACTER`. (This would be a single character, same as `char(1)`.) Please provide your actual table definition - what you get with `\t tbl` in psql.

Comment: CREATE TABLE edges (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  vertex_out INT,
  vertex_in INT,
  label CHARACTER VARYING (255),
  CONSTRAINT fk_vertex_out FOREIGN KEY (vertex_out) REFERENCES vertices (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_vertex_in FOREIGN KEY (vertex_in) REFERENCES vertices (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Comment: (1) Are those `//` "comments" really in your SQL? (2) Are you using string interpolation to build your SQL?

Comment: No, I just added them there to let people understand. when i update, these comments are removed.

Comment: i use debug to find out where the error happens. Its after update 3000 rows, then throw this syntax problem. i looked at the data from 3000 row, found the first label with "[" is [QIOException;], this will be saved in one object, for example obj. when i update the table, i will save it as 'obj.toString()', which is replaced by '[abc]'

Comment: Can you get (intercept) a raw SQL query that is send to Postgres from your application? Is it using SQL parameters or string interpolation?

Comment: BTW The problem might be in the row before the one you are loking at. (Previous row could contain a `'` in its data).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem here is string interpolation in SQL query (it is a **very** bad practice).

Look at this example:

```
  values
      (1,234,235,'[abc]''),
      (2,234,5585,'[def]')
```

The `'` symbol in the name of the first object breaches the string boundaries causing `ERROR: syntax error at or near "[":` on the second line.

You can search for `SQL Injection` in the internet to get details about this problem.

Comment: i didnot have 2 ' ' in the first object.

Comment: could u explain a bit more about it. becuase when obj.toString() = abc, it could update table with 'abc' value. when obj.toString() = [abc], i cant update with this '[abc]'

Comment: @user3895614 Can you get a raw query, that is send to Postgres? After the query is built in your application. Or just show the application code.

Comment: btw, i think it might because of ";", my data is  '[QIOException;]', maybe not caused by "[" but ";" ????   before i update, object [QIOException] is converted to string, so it shouldnot cause the problem

Comment: @user3895614 You are getting `syntax error at or near "["`. This means that the symbol `[` is outside the string (outside a pair if `'`). This can happen in 2 cases: 1) You forgot to add `'` 2) Something "broke" your string. The string can be brocken by `'` or some other symbols, but not by `[` or `;`